# MVC Dependent List linked to model (not static list)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue getting a dependent list to work when linking to the MVC model.  In the other responses online they use static lists do demonstrate (which I can get to work), but I am missing this one last step to link to my real data.  When I do the code below, nothing happens.

My guess it is one simple line I need in the javascript part that I use to set the list (right under the "WORKS SO FAR" alert).  Or it seems there should be a way to just update the dropdownlistfor with my new selectlist (instead of using the each method to push one by one).

Controller:

```
public class EMPLOYEEsController : Controller
{
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.STATEID = new SelectList(db.STATEs, "STATEID", "STATENAME");
    ViewBag.CITYID = new SelectList(db.CITYs, "CITYID", "CITYNAME");
    return View();
}

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdateCity(string id)
    {
        SelectList CityList = new SelectList(db.CITYs.Where(x => x.STATEID.Equals(id)), "CITYID", "CITYNAME");
        return Json(CityList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model myproj.Models.EMPLOYEE

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#STATEID').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCity")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                data: { id: $(this).val() },
                success: function (CityList) {
                    alert('WORKS SO FAR');
                    var citySelect = $('#CITYID');
                    citySelect.empty();
                    $.each(CityList, function (index, locations) {
                        citySelect.append(
                            $('<option/>')
                                .attr('value', CityList.CITYID)
                                .text(CityList.CITYNAME)
                            );
                    });
               },
                error: function() { alert('ERROR'); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="form-horizontal">
<h4>EMPLOYEE</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EMPLOYEENAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EMPLOYEENAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EMPLOYEENAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.STATEID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.STATEID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.STATEs, "Select State", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.STATEID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CITYID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CITYID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CITYs, "Select City", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CITYID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: In your `$.each(CityList, function(index, locations) { console.log(CityList, index, locations); }` what do you observe?

Comment: My CityList looks good in the console.  [Object, Object, Object, Object] It has 4 detailed Objects with proper Text and Value

Comment: I assume `ViewBag.STATEID = ...` and `ViewBag.CITYID = ...` are typos. Based on your view its `ViewBag.STATEs = ...` and `ViewBag.CITYs = ...` otherwise you have other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CityList` is your list of cities. However, you are trying to get the `CityList.CityID`. What you want is the `CityId` and `CityName` of the current city which `$.each` provides as the second parameter in the callback.

You should be able to get it with:

```
                   $.each(CityList, function (index, locationSelectItem) {
                        citySelect.append(
                            $('<option/>')
                                .attr('value', locationSelectItem.Text)
                                .text(locationSelectItem.Value)
                            );
                    });
```

While it makes sense to have StateId and CityId be SelectList since they will be used by the view, you should change your UpdateCity to return a List

Comment: thanks.  great catch.  but it still doesn't work.  it doesn't seem to be updating my second list at all.  I did some more testing and commented out the whole .each section, leaving just the citySelect.empty(), and this doesn't clear the old list.

Comment: Right after your `alert()`, can you `console.log(CityList)` and see what you get back?

Comment: I get back:
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
It has 4 detailed Objects with proper Text and Value.

Comment: There is your problem. It is returning a SelectList, not a List of City. Updated my response

Comment: Is there a problem with my:  var citySelect = $('#CITYID');  Is there a better way to reference the existing list, like somehow tag it with an id?

Comment: I changed it to using your locationSelectItem, but still no luck.  But if it's better to use a List instead of SelectList, I'll do that--can you let me know how to update UpdateCity to create a list from the model instead of SelectList?

Comment: `var CityList = db.CITYs.Where(x => x.STATEID.Equals(id)).ToList();`

Comment: You should not be returning `List<CITY>` (there is no point sending extra data across the wire - just return a collection of anonymous objects containing only the properties you need - `var CityList = db.CITYs.Where(x => x.STATEID == id).Select(x => new { Value =x. CITYID, Text = x.CITYNAME });` Otherwise this answer is correct.

Comment: Completely agree w/ Stephen. Return the collection of anonymous objects.

Comment: SUCCESS!!  Thank you for pointing me toward the best way to grab the data.  It turns out there was one more step I needed as well.

This wasn't working:   var citySelect = $('#CITYID');

Instead I gave the list an id tag and used that (and everything worked):

var citySelect = $('#mylist');

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CITYID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CITYs, "Select City", new { @id="mylist", @class = "form-control" })

Comment: @PaulX, You do not need add an `id` attribute. The` DropDownListFor()` has already added `id="CITYID"` (and if `var citySelect = $('#CITYID');` was not working then you have other problems with your code (such as duplicate `id` attributes)